# Attributed string in tableviewcell not showing bold text until the cell is dequeued and reloaded

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a table view, in which the cells have a label with some attributed text. The text is being set correctly from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The color of the text is being correctly set but the bold attribute is not being displayed until the cell is dequeued.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        Model *model = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell updateContentWithModel:model atIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
}


- (void)updateContentWithModel:(Model *)model atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
self.model = model;
[self setTextFromModel];
[self setImageFromModelAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void) setTextFromModel
{
self.title.text = self.model.header;
self.status.attributedText = [self boldString:self.model.status fontSize:self.status.font.pointSize color:[UIColor redColor]];
}

+(NSMutableAttributedString *)boldString:(NSString *)stringToBold fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize color:(UIColor *)color
{
NSMutableAttributedString *boldString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringToBold];
[boldString setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
                            NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize]} range:NSMakeRange(0, boldString.length)];
return boldString;
}
```

Has anyone experience something like this before?

Comment: Are you calling `setNeedsDisplay`?

Comment: It would help to show the code you use to build the attributed string and assign it to the label

Comment: Is setNeedsDisplay needed?
I am not using drawRect for anything and labels are automatically updated when you update the text. My issue is that the label is updating to the attributed text but the bold attribute seems to be missing/lost until the cell has been dequeued.

Comment: Can you show your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?  Is that where you're assigning the label?

Comment: And now the `updateContentWithModel::` is missing.

Comment: @Cen92, I'm seeing the same thing.  Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Cen92 nvm just got it...I had to make sure I didn't set label.font to a non-nil value.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I am experiencing this issue now.

Comment: @KarenAnne yes by setting the label text from willDisplayCell.

Comment: Hi @Cen92 Yes, I also did the same thing! 

Answer (score 6):

I have same problem due to UIAppearance. Set font\color to nil before setting UILabel attributed text works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.  I was trying to set attributed text (specifically font color) on a UILabel in my custom UITableViewCell and it was only partially reflecting the change, even if I did it in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` (which I believe is the recommended place to do such updates).

It turned out that I needed to **set the property on the main thread**:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [label setAttributedText:text];
        });
```

While I was already aware that all UI updates are to be done on the main thread, I was frankly surprised that `willDisplayCell` wasn't already called from the main thread, at least not in this case.

Comment: Imho this should be the accepted answer, no need to tinker with setting specific properties to nil to make it magically work.. Beware, though, that in case of multiline text, the text should be set first before the dispatch block and then again inside the dispatch block. If you don't, the label won't resize.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that I was using custom subclass of UILabel, which was using UIAppearance for colors. When I switched to using regular UILabel the issue got resolved, but now I had to handle font color myself, instead of using UIAppearance