# UITableViewCell's attributed text not updating

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a table view that is connected through a Core Data's `NSFetchedResultsControler`. The cells have a `UILabel` with attributed text and a `UISwitch` representing the object's `isEnabled` value. Inside the cell, I have a function:

```
func configure(with viewModel: CellViewModel) {
    myCustomLabel.attributedText = viewModel.attributedText // NSMutableAttributedText
}
```

Chaning the switch changes the `isEnabled` value on the object, which in cause raises the `NSFetchedResultsControler`, which calls:

```
let cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) //my custom helper method
let cellViewModel = viewModel.itemModel(at: indexPath)
cell.configure(with: cellViewModel)
```

I do not want to use `reloadData`, `reloadRows` or `reloadSections`, because I want to keep animations while changing the cell's state and avoid cell fading animation if only switch is flipped. I know this is quite bad approach but it's required to keep the animations.

The problem is: **The `attributedText` doesn't change on the label immediately. Only after cell is reused.** The debugger displays the new value of the label correctly. I have tried:

- [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38099408/4420197) (setting font and color to `nil` beforehand),
- calling `setNeedDisplay` on both the label and it's superview
- setting the non-attributed text first, then `attributedText`

Nothing works. Do you have any ideas why it's like that?

System is iOS 11.4, XCode 9.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that instead of:

```
let cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

You should use:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

That will return you the cell instance for that indexPath. By calling "dequeueReusableCell" you are essentially saying you want a new Cell.

That assumes that I get what you are trying to achieve and your snippet is not from the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

method.

If that doesn't work might be worth adding a git link to take a look at your code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap `myCustomLabel.attributedText = viewModel.attributedText` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` it will work:

`DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    myCustomLabel.attributedText = viewModel.attributedText
}`